# Why does differentiating the normalization term of a Binomial Distribution yield the expected value?

Tags: machine-learning, binomial-distribution, expected-value, pattern-recognition

In Bishop's book Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, problem 2.4 aims to derive the expected value of the binomial distribution $m \sim Bin(N, \mu) = {N \choose m} \mu^m (1 - \mu)^{N-m}$ by differentiating the normalizing constant $\sum_{m=0}^N {N \choose m} \mu^m (1-\mu)^{N-m}$ with respect to the parameter $\mu$. I can algebraically solve the problem, but why does differentiating this normalizing constant yield $\mathbb{E}[m]$?

Edit: To clarify, I'm asking **WHY** this result emerges, not how. I can do the algebra myself.

Comment: [Bishop's book](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) has an Exercise 2.4 but it only ask you to derive this "directly using calculus".

Comment: You can do something resembling what you're suggesting using [probability generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Probabilities_and_expectations) but this involves differentiating w.r.t. to the argument of the pgf.

Comment: If you instead differentiate $\sum_{m=0}^N {N \choose m} \mu^m (1-\mu)^{N-m}$ w.r.t. $\mu$ you clearly get zero since the sum always equals 1 so I'm voting to close your question as unclear.

Comment: $\mu$ is so commonly used to denote the _mean_ or expected value of a random variable (and $p$ is so commonly used to denote the second parameter in the usual notation for a binomial random variable) that it is disconcerting to see its very different meaning here. Perhaps there is much to the notion that machine learning and statistics/probability are two very different subjects that have little to do with one another.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I agree that the notation is minorly disconcerting, but I kept it for consistency with the textbook. If you want me to switch to the more common $p$ notation, I'd be happy to.

Comment: @JarleTufto , not quite. You clearly get zero on one side, but the other side isn't zero, and from the other side, you can calculate the expected value of $m$, as dnqxt showed below.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326833/mean-of-exponential-families and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387880/relationship-between-exponential-families-and-moment-generating-functions.  For more like these, [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=exponential+family+mean).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate $$\sum_{m=0}^N {N \choose m} \mu^m (1-\mu)^{N-m} = 1
$$ 
wrt $\mu$, to get:
$$\sum_{m=0}^N {N \choose m}  m\mu^{m-1} (1-\mu)^{N-m} 
= \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} {N \choose m} \mu^{m} (N-m) (1-\mu)^{N-m-1} 
$$

Note that the derivative of $\mu$ terms is $m\mu^{m-1} (1-\mu)^{N-m} - \mu^{m} (N-m)(1-\mu)^{N-m-1}.$

Also, note that the upper limit in the RHS must be $N-1$ (why?).

LHS becomes:
$$\frac{1}{\mu}\sum_{m=0}^N {N \choose m}  m\mu^{m} (1-\mu)^{N-m}=\frac{1}{\mu}Em.
$$

RHS:

$$
\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}  \frac{N!}{m!(N-m)!}\mu^{m} (N-m) (1-\mu)^{N-m-1} 
= \\
N \sum_{m=0}^{N-1}  \frac{(N-1)!}{m!(N-m-1)!}\mu^{m} (1-\mu)^{N-m-1} = \\ N (\mu + (1-\mu))^{N-1}=N.
$$

The last equality follows from the binomial theorem. Thus, $Em=\mu N.$

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't my question. My question is **why** this result emerges, not how.

Comment: Answering 'how' usually sheds some light on 'why' although it may not give satisfactory info. In this case, I'd say that the result follows because differentiation, in one step, ties together the values of the binomial r.v. with its corresponding probabilities, with some terms happily cancelling or summing to a simple expression as given above. I don't see a deeper cause...

Comment: I agree - it just happens to work that way in this case.  If you try differentiating the normalizing constant for, say, the Poisson or Normal distributions with respect to the parameter that equals the mean, you don't get the mean.  (If it hadn't worked that way, the question wouldn't be in the book!)

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate the clarification.